# Update a var with a switcher function in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new in Python please a little compassion if it is very strange what I am trying to do, after several attempts I have not able to update certain key: pairs in a dictionary in the variable (messageInit) with a function switcher (switcherMessage(args)), My goal is to be able to trigger a particular method, depending on the type of message that arrives (in this case I represent them with the message variables), so that it updates only a part of the dictionary (messageInit), and then pass the specified data to another function (otherTask (data)), which in this case only prints them. The strangest thing is that for the first switcher if it works (toActive ()) and it gives me what I expect (the ohter two don't), but honestly I don't understand how variables behave in python, I have experience in js, but here I am confused since, for me it should only be updated.

I appreciate any help or hint in advance.

```
import json

# global dict to hold telemtry
messageInit = {
    'thingId': 'CarlosTal84-Hilda-mggbCoK1pihIqDJzJf3T',
    'active': 'false',
    'motorSpeed': 0,
    'colorValue': {
                    "r":0,
                    "g":0,
                    "b":0
                }
}

# print init data dict
print(f"init var: {messageInit}")

# other func
def otherTask(data):
    print(f"after task: {data}")

# function to handle the receive message
def on_message():

    # message bin arrival
    message =  b'{"active":"true"}'
    # message = b'{"motorSpeed": 20}'
    # message =  b'{"colorValue":{"r":2,"g":10,"b":100}}'

    # hold message in a var
    payload = str(message.decode('utf-8'))

    # print payload var with message
    # print(payload)

    # check if exist data in the payload
    if payload:

        # convert string in obj
        obj = json.loads(payload)

        # switcher func
        def switcherMessage(args):

            # methods
            def toActive():

                global messageInit
                # hold in vars
                messageActive = obj.get("active")
                messageInit.update({"active": messageActive})
                active = messageInit.get("active")
                return active

            def toMotorSpeed():

                global messageInit
                # hold in vars
                messageMotorSpeed = obj.get("motorSpeed")
                messageInit.update({"motorSpeed": messageMotorSpeed})
                motorSpeed = messageInit.get("motorSpeed")
                return motorSpeed

            def toColorValue():

                global messageInit
                # hold in vars
                messageColorValue = obj.get("colorValue")
                messageInit.update({"colorValue": messageColorValue})
                colorValue = messageInit.get("colorValue")
                return colorValue

            # dict switch
            switcher={
                'messageActive': toActive(),
                'messageMotorSpeed': toMotorSpeed(),
                'messageColorValue': toColorValue()
            }

            # return switcher
            return switcher.get(args, lambda:"Shit")

        # Driver program to switcher
        def wichMessage():

            if payload.find("active"):
                return 'messageActive'
            elif payload.find("motorSpeed"):
                return 'messageMotorSpeed'
            elif payload.find("colorValue"):
                return 'messageColorValue'

        # type of message var
        args = wichMessage()

        # run methods to fill vars
        print(switcherMessage(args))

        # other task
        otherTask(switcherMessage(args))

# run it
on_message()

# here the outputs for every switcher:
init var: {'thingId': 'CarlosTal84-Hilda-mggbCoK1pihIqDJzJf3T', 'active': 'false', 'motorSpeed': 0, 'colorValue': {'r': 0, 'g': 0, 'b': 0}}
true
after task: true
>>> 
# second message var
init var: {'thingId': 'CarlosTal84-Hilda-mggbCoK1pihIqDJzJf3T', 'active': 'false', 'motorSpeed': 0, 'colorValue': {'r': 0, 'g': 0, 'b': 0}}
None
after task: None
>>> 
# third message var 
init var: {'thingId': 'CarlosTal84-Hilda-mggbCoK1pihIqDJzJf3T', 'active': 'false', 'motorSpeed': 0, 'colorValue': {'r': 0, 'g': 0, 'b': 0}}
None
after task: None
>>>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to dig through, but your `switcher` dictionary looks off. Note that when you do `switcher={'messageActive': toActive()}`, `toActive` is called when the dictionary is created (and only that time), not when `switcher.get(args, lambda:"Shit")` is called. That means all three of those functions are called when `switcher` is created, then never again (until `switcher` is created again).

Comment: Thanks!! Solve now..